# Router in global navigation always give me / even using relative path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, multi-tenant, angular-routerlink

I'm trying to create an app with a global nav (in AppComponent before router-outlet) and subroutes. The web app is built on the multi-tenant model with an url like this http://serveraddress/tenantSpace/:tenantUrl/ and I can't get the result I want in my routerLinks relative paths. I always get a / instead of full param path.

Here is what I tried:

So the route of each tenant will start after /tenantSpace/:tenantUrl/. So what I have for my routerLinks in my navigation is something like:

```
<a routerLink="./page1">Page1</a>
```

which I expect will give me:

```
<a routerLink="/tenantSpace/tenantSpace1/page1" href="/tenantSpace/tenantSpace1/page1">Page1</a>
```

The problem is that I always get /page1. The relative path is not evaluated even if I'm on a page at the same level as Page1 for example in /tenantSpace/tenantSpace1/page2.

If I put a routerlink inside the page1 component I get the good router.url but when the global navigation in AppComponent is evaluated the router.url is always /

So I'm sure I don't understand the way routing works in Angular and I don't find any ressources on this. If someone could help I would be very grateful.

Here is a stackblitz to illustrate the issue (you will find my route configuration inside):

[Sample project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jgkssh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acutally `./` routing means the relative position of the current route of the component, since its in `app.component` the relative positioning is `/` so angular is working fine!

To solve your problem, you need to create a component called `webspaces` this will contain `<router-outlet/>` inside that we will subscribe the latest value of the params `webSpaceName` and store it in a service. Like so

webspaces.com.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterOutlet, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { WebspaceService } from '../webspace.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-webspaces',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './webspaces.component.html',
  styleUrl: './webspaces.component.scss',
})
export class WebspacesComponent {
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private webspaceService: WebspaceService
  ) {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.webspaceService.webspace = params?.['webSpaceName'] || '';
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

webspaces html

```
<router-outlet/>
```

In the root component when we route, we append the parameter and then perform the routing as shown below!

app html

```
<nav>
  <a [routerLink]="['webspaces', webspace, 'properties']">Properties</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLink, RouterModule, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { WebspaceService } from './webspace.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterModule, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AppTest';

  get webspace() {
    return this.webspaceService.webspace;
  }

  constructor(private webspaceService: WebspaceService) {}
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xexbvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.routes.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fwebspaces%2Fwebspaces.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fwebspaces%2Fwebspaces.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fwebspace.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`

Comment: Ok... I think I better understand the idea of routing now. But the docs are not very clear on this particular use case. An example should be provided on theirs dev website since this is a very common usecase. Be careful that in your code the observable is subcribed after the routerLink is rendered. So the webSpaceName parameter is empty when building the routerLink. Probably better to transform your observable as a signal so that the view is automatically updated ? Thank you so much for your answer I will try to implement such a thing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Naren Murali I ended with something like this:

In AppComponent template :

```
<a [routerLink]="[routerLinkBaseUrl(), 'page1']" routerLinkActive>Page1</a>
```

In my AppComponent.ts :

```
private _router = inject(Router);
public routerLinkBaseUrl = toSignal(this._router.events.pipe(
    filter((e):e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(e => {
      const matches = e.urlAfterRedirects.match(/\/tenants\/[\w-]*\d[\w-]*\/?/g);
      return matches ? matches[0] : "./";
    })
  ), { initialValue: ""});
```

It is not exaclty what you proprosed but I finally used the router events to get the navigationEnd and create a signal based on it.

If someone see a better way to do this...